# how to get online facebook users using the xmpp framework

Tags: ios4, facebook, xmppframework

Requesting the roster via XMPP just gives me a list of all friends. Is there a way to request or determine with users are online (as well as their active / idle status) at the time of the request? I'm using the X-facebook-platform authentication mechanism to fetch only the online facebook friends list.

Please help..

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to request only online users.  The XMPP server will return the entire roster with status information.  You would then query the roster module for the online users.  The concept is similar to the sample apps, which sort by status and display the users in a table view.